# Tastypie ToOneField not working

Tags: django, tastypie

My Models:

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Problem(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(UserDetails)
    onset_time=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    symptoms=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Resources:

```
class ProblemResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset=Problem.objects.all()
        resource_name="hypo"

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    hypo=fields.ToOneField(ProblemResource,'hypo')
    class Meta:
        queryset=UserDetails.objects.all()
        resource_name="user"
```

I want to fetch the problem of a particular user using '/user' api call but I am getting this error:-

{"error": "The model '<UserDetails: UserDetails object>' has an empty attribute 'hypo' and doesn't allow a null value."}

I've been through the data and there are no null values .

Comment: was this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem just by providing `related_name='hypo'` in Problem model

```
class Problem(models.Model):
   user=models.OneToOneField(UserDetails,related_name='hypo')
   onset_time=models.CharField(max_length=20)
   symptoms=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) has more details regarding related_name tag.

Answer (score 0):

What if you specify defaults for null in the model.

```
user=models.OneToOneField(UserDetails, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: I think problem is with 'UserResource' not with 'Problem' model

Comment: Tried your's solution ,but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem over here is the attribute 'hypo' in the UserResource. 
As per the docs attribute means:

> A string naming an instance attribute of the object wrapped by the Resource. The attribute will be accessed during the dehydrate or written during the hydrate.

So in your case inside the UserResource, 'hypo' is not an attribute, 'problem' is the correct attribute (referring your models).

So changing the attribute in the UserResource solves the problem:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    hypo=fields.ToOneField(ProblemResource,'problem')
    class Meta:
        queryset=UserDetails.objects.all()
        resource_name="user"
```

Read more: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#common-field-options